# My project is not running on the android emulator but work with iphone

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, expo

I am quite new here and it has been a couple of days I've been having this issue where the android emulator can't run my project possibly due to a merge conflict.

I have tried relinking and searching for similar issues, no result. Please can anyone help, I really don't have enough points for a bounty or else I would have integrated it. Thank you for your time

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-react-native-adapter'.
Project with path ':expo-core' could not be found in project ':expo-react-native-adapter'.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Comment: Do you use any library other than expo that has native modules?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run project on android emulator but works with Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55944753/unable-to-run-project-on-android-emulator-but-works-with-iphone)